# Query Last Value in Fixed Length Array With Empty Values

Tags: postgresql, array

I have a table that generally looks like:

```
Name varchar       | Location varchar[]
---------------------------------------------
Lemoney    | {Home,Work,Home,Stack Exchange,,,,,,}
Other Dude | {Home,,,,,,,,,}
Busy Dude  | {Home,Work,Work,Work,Home,Work,,,,}
```

I have been trying to write a query that will return the Last Value for each Name like:

```
Lemony     | Stack Exchange
Other Dude | Home
Busy Dude  | Work
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to return that yet. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is location an array column, e.g. `text[]`?

Comment: VARCHAR[] my apologies.. fixing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct Name, loc 
FROM (
  SELECT  *, last_value(Location) over (partition by Name) as loc 
    FROM (SELECT Name, unnest(Location) as Location FROM table)  x) y;
```

Should answer your question